# Make python find() disregard literals

Tags: python-2.7, find

I'm using `txt.find(search_txt)` in python 2.7 to find a short string in a larger one.  But if there happens to be a `\n` in the middle of `search_txt` in the larger string, `find()` doesn't work.  Is there a way to make `find()` ignore literals?

Comment: Find works with newlines, for example, `"foo\nbar\nbaz".find("bar\nbaz")`. Do you have an example?

Comment: Try the file at this link:  https://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/BILLS-114hr5852ih/html/BILLS-114hr5852ih.htm .  If I search for "is amended" it misses the first result.  It doesn't look like there's a `\n` character there.  But when I downloaded the file and printed it with repr() it looked like the the first result was "is \namended".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to expand what counts as a match. By setting MULTILINE mode, a newline is considered white space. This regex matches `a \namended` but would also match `as   \t\t amended`. That's likely okay for what you want. matches return a `SRE_Match` object which has the index where the string is found.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r'is\s+amended', 'foo bar is \namended baz',flags=re.MULTILINE)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fbeffa396b0>
```